# How to pass data from OWIN UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication, AuthorizationCodeReceived notification back to the controller?

Tags: owin, openid, openid-connect

I configured the AppBuilder to use OpenIdConnectAuthentication and I added the [Authorize] header on the endpoint I want the authentication to be applied.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = ClientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;

                        await Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
```

});

How can I send the variable code back to the controller? Here there is no HttpContext, and the OwinContext I have access token is different than the one in the controller.

Comment: Can I ask why you want the code back to the controller? A more common scenario would be, in that `AuthorizationCodeReceived` event, to hit the token endpoint on your OIDC provider to exchange the code against tokens so you can finalise the authentication process.

Comment: the code would be cleaner this way. but will try it there, thanks.

Comment: I have a bunch of dependencies that I read from the route and controller, and cannot put it there.